# Are there functions so that $f(n) \notin \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ and $g(n) \notin \mathcal{O}(f(n))$?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Note that the functions should be $\mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$.

So I was thinking about something like
$$f(x) = 1 + \sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})$$
$$g(x) = 1 + \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})$$ 
which would work I guess.

However, would it still be possible if **both** functions had to be monotonic increasing (not necessary strictly!)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Inductively: $f(1) = g(1) = 1$ and
\begin{align*}
 f(2 \, n) &= f(2 \, n - 1) \\
 g(2 \, n) &= n \, f(2 \, n) \\
 g(2 \, n+1) &= g(2 \, n) \\
 f(2 \, n+1) &= n \, g(2 \, n + 1)
\end{align*}
for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Great answer! An explicit definition would be  
$f(n) = (n - 1 + (n \mod 2))!$ and  
$g(n) = (n - (n \mod 2))!$.

Comment: Actually, this is looking better: $f(n) = (2 * \lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor + 1)!$ and $g(n) = (2 * \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)!$